# run a program on logon screen

Tags: windows, boot

Is it possible? I want to autostart an exe program as soon windows starts and the Login Screen is there? Can someone please provide me steps to add program to startup?

I can add a program to startup but it only runs as soon as user logged in, but I want to run it behind the scenes when PC is on login screen.

Using Windows 2003 Sever DataCenter edition

Comment: You'll need to be more specific as to what this program does, IE is it interactive or should it act like a service? If it's not interactive this is possible, if you want it to be interactive it may be more tricky, maybe not possible.

Comment: I want to add a DNS updater tool as startup. see dnsdynamic.org

Comment: As duenni says below, use srvany from the resource toolkit, you can use it to turn things in to a service that runs in the background. If you need specific assistance in doing so let me know.

Comment: can you provide me some detailed steps? how to use srvany.exe?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to start your program as a Windows Service. The Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools, located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657), contain the program srvany.exe which can run applications as Windows Services.
This won't work with everything, it depends on your program.